# strcpy() alternative for integers and doubles - c

Tags: c, struct, strcpy

So I used this code in order to pass a variable in to my struct:

```
strcpy(s[i].orderName, Name);
```

and it works how I want it to. However, the rest of my variables are integers and a double and it appears there is no "intcpy()" alternative from what I have found. Is there another way to pass integer and double variables in to my struct?

Thank you.

Comment: Just use a simple assignment: `s[i].int_var = 6`

Comment: or `memcpy(&s[i].var,&value,sizeof(value))`. But assignment is less complex.

Comment: @Pablo Wow, thanks. I tried 6 = s[i].var; earlier but it didn't work. Didn't think the solution would be so simple.

Comment: The assignment works the other way round!

Comment: @Jean-FrancoisFabre Thanks, i think i'll go the assignment route.

Comment: @Ibrahim The reason you need to use `strcpy()` to  write a string into an array variable has *nothing* to do with it being inside a struct, and *everything* to do with the fact that it's an array.

Comment: I did know about assignments, I just tried it the wrong way round when I did it, and assumed I couldn't do it that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple assignment `=` for the `int` variables:

```
struct abc {
    int a;
    int b;
};

void foo(int b)
{
    struct abc x;

    x.a = 8;
    x.b = b;


    printf("x.a: %d\n, x.b: %d\n", x.a, x.b);
}
```